# How to set static routes in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: networking, routing

I have used Ubuntu since Ubuntu 8.10; today I'm working with Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

I am having difficulty keeping static routes on booting. I would usually put the route commands

```
/sbin/route add -net <IP>/<MASK> <GW> dev <ethX>
```

in `/etc/rc.local` or I would create a file (named `routes`) inside the directory `/etc/network/if-up/`, but I notice that on Ubuntu 12.04 it isn't working.

If I type the commands in the shell, they work, but the same commands don't work when they  are in the specified file.

I already tried to change the file name to other names thinking that my file name (`routes`) could be erroneous in Ubuntu 12.04, but that also did not work.

I notice also that command `/sbin/ifconfig` works, less the `/sbin/route`.

What changed in network set-up?

How can I define static routes on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Just to check: is rc.local executable and it starts with the shebang line? Maybe its a problem with your command. You can try redirect stderr to a file (`your_command > stderr.txt 2>&1`) and inspect its output...

Comment: You should set routes in /etc/network/interfaces, not in /etc/rc.local.
And new commands you should use is `ip add` and `ip route`. One command to rule the net. :)

Comment: Definitely read `man 5 interfaces`

Answer (score 75):

You can put static routes in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.1.2
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1
      up route add -net 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.240.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Syntax for /sbin/ip: `up ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1`

Comment: Would you kindly explain your last two lines in the answer or provide a link to the knowledge source? Thanks!

Comment: You can view -net 192.68.0.0 as a wildcard, saying all packets destined for 192.168.*.* should be routed via the default gateway 192.168.1.1. The kernel will then try to resolve that default gateway but if it has an ARP entry already, then it will send the packet out the interface it has learned that gateway resides on with the destination MAC for that next hop. Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: There is also /etc/network/interfaces.d/ which may be a better place to put the route.

Comment: This works, but it is not described in the man pages for network interfaces. Is this standard?

Comment: @BЈовић It is described in 16.04 interfaces man page under section [IFACE OPTIONS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/interfaces.5.html#iface%20options): "**up** *command*". The interfaces manual page for 18.04 was modified. **up** is listed in [ifupdown-addons-interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/ifupdown-addons-interfaces.5.html).

Comment: Cool. Thanks. That is new to me, as I was looking some ancient man pages from debian and who knows what. It would be good to add those link to the answer :)

Comment: For newer versions of Ubuntu (>18) and NetworkManager please refer to @ofirule solution.

Comment: As it is 2021, you should no longer configure /etc/network/* or use ifup or ifdown. On **Desktop** systems use **NetworkManager** (see the answer of @ofirule), on **Server** systems use **netplan** (see answer of @Iman Kermani).

Answer (score 20):

I found very often that the correct place to define a static route is in /etc/network/interfaces,  it is ok if you are going to globally restart the network with /etc/init.d/networking restart for example. But if you are going to use ifdown and ifup to individually shutdown an interface, ifup will end with the error:

```
ifup eth1

RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1.
```

Because of it tries to define a route but it is already defined. The interface will be up anyway but, ifup will not update /run/network/ifstate so next time you will us ifdown you will not able to do it unless you use the --force flag.

To make ifup to continue configuring even if routes are already defined, you can use this format when defining routes in /etc/network/interfaces

```
up ip route add 172.16.0.0/24 via 192.168.10.1 || true
up ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 via 192.168.10.1 || true
```

This way you will have the warning in the output but the interface configuration will be completed

```
ifup eth1

RTNETLINK answers: File exists
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 18553
```

Comment: Why not simply add a "down ip route del 192.168.0.0/16 via 192.168.10.1" to the config?

Comment: Because people do things like use `ifconfig` manually, instead of running `ifdown`, then want to be able to recover by using the correct tools.  Thus it's helpful if those tools are resilient to unexpected state as they try to fix the state.  The `|| true` suggestion is a good one.  Adding a down line _too_ is helpful.

Comment: *From a random user:* Use "replace" instead of "add" in the ip command. Ex:
`up ip route replace 172.16.0.0/24 via 192.168.10.1` "replace" would add the route if it doesn't exist yet, but if a route with the same selector exists it would be replaced by the current one, even if they have the same destination.

Answer (score 10):

As it is 2021 you can config it using `netplan` on ubuntu 18.04 or later (tested on ubuntu 20.04).
*compelete reference is available on [netplan site](https://netplan.io/reference/)*.
the config file can be found under `/etc/netplan/` directory.

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens160: # in my case the interface name is ens160
      dhcp4: false  # or true. depends on your situation
      addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]  # your static IP address
      # the actual answer is here
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0  # or any other subnet you like. 0.0.0.0/0 means default gateway
          via: 172.16.0.1  # or any other gateway you want.
          on-link: true   # as you see my interface IP address and default gateway are not in the same subnet so we should put this true but if they are in the same subnet this is not required.
```

PS. the YAML configuration files are sensitive to indentation and it does not accept tabs. the indentation is 2 spaces.

don't forget run `netplan apply`.

Comment: This was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can try this (add it to `/etc/network/interfaces`), this is almost complete way for setting routes:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    post-up /sbin/route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1
    post-up /bin/mount -t nfs 192.168.0.203:/motd/ /motd/
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a package **ifupdown-extra** avaible in Ubuntu.
It provides automatic scripts (installed in `/etc/network/*/`), one of which is used to add static routes.

The configuration file for this is  `/etc/network/routes`

The top of this config file has a good description:

> This configuration file is read by the static-routes if-updown script
>   and the /etc/init.d/networking-routes script to setup a list of routes
>   associated either with a given interface or global routes.

An example route I use is:

```
192.168.240.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.130.3 em3
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `nmcli` I was able to run a persistent solution (@isapir solution didn't work on my device).

```
sudo nmcli connection modify <conection-name> +ipv4.routes "<ip>/<mask> <gw> <mt>"
```

For example:

```
sudo nmcli connection modify ssid-name +ipv4.routes "1.1.1.0/24 192.168.0.1 100"
```

After that applying the changes is possible by setting the connection down and up again (no need for full NetworkManager restart):

```
sudo nmcli con down ssid-name ; sudo nmcli con up ssid-name
```

To see current connections run:

```
sudo nmcli connection
```

Comment: This answer should be use. As it is permanent after reboot and also works with newer versions of Ubuntu and NetworkManager. Also for those who don't know, if you want to your route has the most priority use `0` metric: 
`sudo nmcli connection modify ssid-name +ipv4.routes "1.1.1.0/24 192.168.0.1 0"`

Comment: As NetworkManager is only available (by default) on desktop systems: if it is not available, you should use **netplan** - see the answer of @"Iman Kermani".

@"Pouria Moosavi": The primary match for a route is the prefix length (== most specific route to a network). The metric is only evaluated thereafter.

Answer (score 3):

what worked for us was

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.0.2/32 gw 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
```

i used to run on a Mac:

```
sudo route -n add -net 192.168.0.2/32 192.168.1.1
```

but on a ubuntu the "gw" between IPs and the last "netmask" part was missing (also -n not required on ubuntu)

Comment: this works perfectly for temporary (non-persistant) routes, the question is about getting routes persistent

Comment: Not working `SIOCADDRT: Invalid argument `

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `nmcli`.

```
nmcli device modify <device> +ipv4.routes "<ip>/<mask> <gw>" ipv4.route-metric 0
```

For example:

```
nmcli device modify wlp2s0 +ipv4.routes "1.1.1.0/24 192.168.0.1" ipv4.route-metric 0
```

After that apply the changes by restarting the NetworkManager service:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: nmcli device... commands will not persist on reboot. nmcli connection... commands will. see @ofirule solution.