# Ubuntu 12.04 - how can i have eth0 and wlan0 both active where eth0 is primary and wlan0 is just for internet browse

Tags: 12.04, command-line, wireless, networking, ethernet

I have a box running Ubuntu 12.04. There i have eth0 which is used as local network no internet. But i have also in that same box wlan0, and WiFi availability.

Now how can i have both interface active? So that eth0 remain as it is, but wlan0 also get auto active to specific WiFi as fixed. When ever internet inbound/outbound access requires, i want to use wlan0 interface, not the eth0 interface as it is used already for webservice in local networks.

Any ideas how to achieve this? ( i tried this but not working for both interface https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your **eth0** interface is *routed* to your local network, while your **wlan0** interface is *routed* to the outside world.  Consider establishing routes for your two interfaces as shown [at this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168033/how-to-set-routes).

For more information about *routes*, visit [this page](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/VPN-HOWTO/x425.html) at The Linux Documentation Project.