# Set up permanent routing (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: 13.04, networking, routing

I have 2 connections: *wlan0* (gw: 192.168.1.1) and *eth0* (gw: 192.168.2.1).
My default connection is *wlan0*, but I wanted some websites load through my *eth0*, so I set up **routing** for those websites/IPs like this:

```
route add -net 31.135.208.0/21 gw 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
```

This works, however **is not permanent** (disappears after reboot). I tried to put this code in `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
up route add -net 31.135.208.0/21 gw 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
```

but when I restart Ubuntu, it starts without networking (it crashes). I also put these lines into that file:

```
auto eth0
address 192.168.2.125
gateway 192.168.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

but still system boots without networking.

Currently I have put `route` command into `/etc/rc.local`, it works, but it is not permanent, because when I restart/re-connect my *eth0* (for some reason), routing disappears.

Some notes:
I have long list of IPs to route.
My router, which I connected *eth0* is set to DHCP.
I tried to connect *eth0* both static and DHCP way.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 11):

On my system it worked when i made a script in the folder `/etc/network/if-up.d/` called `script` with execute permissions 755:

```
#ls -la /etc/network/if-up.d/script
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   46 Okt 15 11:46 script
```

There you can add command to execute when the connection is established, in your case:

```
#cat /etc/network/if-up.d/script
#!/bin/bash
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" == "eth0" ] || exit 0
# Adding additional routes on connection
route add -net 31.135.208.0/21 gw 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
route add ...
route add ...
```

You don't need to add something in `/etc/network/interfaces` besides `auto eth0` and iface `eth0 inet dhcp` or whatever you have there. NetworkManager invokes the scripts in this directory by `exec run-parts /etc/network/if-up.d` in the script `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown`.
You can test this by (in my case):

```
# run-parts --test /etc/network/if-up.d
/etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
/etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd
/etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
/etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
/etc/network/if-up.d/ip
/etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
/etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
/etc/network/if-up.d/openvpn
/etc/network/if-up.d/script <---- your script here
/etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
/etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
```

Comment: Nice answer - if you need to make the routes specific to one interface, so they only get added when eth0 is connected, try adding: `[ "$IFACE" != "eth0" ] || exit 0` before the route add lines.

Comment: Good proposal, i added you line.

Comment: @chaos, thanks for answer. However script does not run when I connect to eth0. But it works when I run like this: run-parts /etc/network/if-up.d

Comment: So your NM isn't invoking the script or it isn't existing. Can you please post the output of `ps faux | grep -i network`, `cat /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown | grep run-parts` and `nm-tool`

Comment: @chaos , thank you for taking time to help me, here you go: http://pastebin.com/dNZMsHn7

Comment: So, I think i figured it out. First, your networking isn't starting because the syntax in `/etc/network/interfaces` is wrong. Second, for your concern it isn't recommended to use `/etc/network/interfaces` for managing this interface because every time you replug the cable, you need to `/etc/init.d/networking restart` to tun the if-up.d script to set the routes again. So, delete everything in the interfaces file relating to the eth0 interface. Then, do a `/etc/init.d/networking restart` and `/etc/init.d/network-manager restart` and make sure that "Enable Networking" is checked in the NM-Applet.

Comment: @chaos, in `/etc/network/interfaces` I have following only: `auto lo
iface lo inet loopback` There is nothing relating to eth0..

Answer (score 8):

The syntax for adding routes to you interfaces is as follows:

```
up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

You don't need to add the device to the end.

Example interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.1.2
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

Based on info from: [How to set static routes in Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168033/how-to-set-routes)