# Routing table for Ubuntu Server with Static route not correct at startup

Tags: networking, server

I'm having a strange issue with a new Ubuntu server VM install in ESXi. With DHCP enabled in `/etc/network/interfaces` all network connectivity works fine. However, when i use a static route with the following parameters the routing table is wrong at startup:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens192
iface ens192 inet static
address 192.168.70.21/24
gateway 192.168.168.70.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.70.1
```

With the above in place, the machine can still reach all machines on the 192.168.70.0/24 network but not any other local network (there are many). A `ping` to any other local network would immediately return `connect: Network is unreachable`.

When i run `route -n` I get the following which is wrong:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.70.1    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0           U    0   0        0  ens192
```

It should be this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.70.1   0.0.0.0              UG    0   0        0  ens192
192.168.70.1    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0           U    0   0        0  ens192
```

Even my `/etc/resolve.conf` isn't getting the nameserver (it has none). So to temporarily get around the problem, I added a route:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.70.1
```

Now the machine can access all other local networks allowed in pfsense (192.168.15.0/24, 192.168.38.0/24, etc), and they can reach it. But even with this work around i have to [add google nameservers](https://askubuntu.com/a/91595/190762) to reach the web.

I have another Ubuntu Server VM in ESXi on the same network and it works fine with just the `/etc/network/interfaces` parameters above (with different static IP). So I'm not sure what is going on with this fresh Ubuntu16.04 LTS server install.

I realize i can [add a permanent route](https://askubuntu.com/a/168037/190762) but that seems like a hack in this case because that wasn't required in the other Ubuntu VM with a static route. How do i correct this properly?

Comment: AFAIK `192.168.70.21/24` isn't a valid IPv4 address (it's a CIDR address *range*), and `192.168.168.70.1` isn't a valid gateway address either.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, The error was in the `192.168.168.70.1` typo. After fixing that, everything is working correctly. As far as `192.168.70.21/24` not being a valid address, it is an alternative way to specify both the address and the netmask on a single line. It is also outlined in `man interfaces` as a way to set static ip.