# How to route traffic to a set of IP address (or domains if possible) from wifi rather than LAN port?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, dns, router

I have two internet connections (different ISPs), one via LAN another via Wifi.
I want to connect to a few websites (for which I know the IP addresses) through wifi but I want to connect to other networks through LAN port.

Right now, I switch off LAN port to access those websites by wifi, is there any permanent solution to achieve this?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set static routes in Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168033/how-to-set-static-routes-in-ubuntu-server)

Comment: Essentially you just need a permanent version of `sudo ip route add w.x.y.z/32 dev wlan0`